# Install a package via composer scripts

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Is it possible to install a package via composer scripts ?

There are some scripts executing during symfony/framework-standard-edition installation by sensio/distribution-bundle. So i crated my own script which basically asks to user for which packages will be installed.

for example;

```
public static function installPackages(CommandEvent $event ){
   $packages = $event->ask('Which packages do you want to install?',null)
   if(is_null($packages)){
     return;
   }
    //i assume the answer is "vendor/repo,vendor/repo2"
   $arr = explode(',',$packages);
   foreach($arr as $item){
      //install item..
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to have this (executing `composer install` -> then answer your question) as a replacement for executing `composer require vendor/repo:*`? What is the difference? The user needs to know how to use the CLI interface, and needs to know the package name and version requirement in both cases.

Comment: i am trying to create a script for my vendor. i only worry about that is it possible install it via scripts?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do? Why do you want to ask about installing more new packages during installing or updating the current packages? This seems to mix things that should be separate.

Comment: i am creating this template for people who dont know anything about composer. they only know composer create project.

Comment: for example framework standar edition of symfony asks to install Acme demo bundle. why symfony asks this question?

Comment: You want to prepare templates for PHP developers who don't know Composer. How would they know about Composer packages? How would they know which packages they want? Why should they only learn to install Composer and run "create-project", when the next step to add packages with Composer directly is way easier? Do you know that Composer also supports an interactive mode that allows searching for packages and picking versions? My guess: If the developer is able to run Composer on the command line, he is able to add packages. And for the record: I don't know what Symfony does, and why.

Comment: we are a web company that uses symfony framework. we have a lot of projects (about 95-100) currently created and installed manually without composer. i created a new template which use composer succesfully and i want to re-create all old projects with this new template. i know, there are a lot of methods(bash scripts, git submodules etc..)  to do this but i want to play with composer scripts.

Comment: So this is a one-time project recreation? You have to find out which versions of Symfony and other bundles you were using, find their current name within Packagist, and add them as dependency to the project while removing the old files from version control.

Comment: Doing this in a composer hook is not the best idea. You would need to call composer from withing the composer, in order for a package to be successfully installed, and for the lock file and autoloader to be updated. Bash script is probably a better tool for the job you're trying to do.

I think it's time that your colleague developers upgrade their skills and learn composer.

Comment: We stopped to use composer hook scripts for that reason. we created a symfony standard edition template. We are running `composer require vendor/bundle vendor/bundle2` after template installation. Of course, upgrading skills always better so i learned too much things about composer and i am sharing my experiences with them. thanks for your advises.